# How Autofac helps You to inject multiple instances of a class/interface in an existing class at the same time

Tags: c#, autofac, ioc-container

I'm very new to Autofac and don't understand still all the potential.
Let's take the example considered in the quick autofac tutorial in the website documentation. (https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting-started/index.html)

```
using System;

namespace DemoApp
{

 public interface IOutput
 {
   void Write(string content);
 }

 public class ConsoleOutput : IOutput
 {
    public void Write(string content)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(content);
    }
  }

  public interface IDateWriter
  {
     void WriteDate();
  }

  public class TodayWriter : IDateWriter
  {
     private IOutput _output;
     public TodayWriter(IOutput output)
     {
         this._output = output;
     }

     public void WriteDate()
     {
         this._output.Write(DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString());
     }
 }
}
```

And the Autofac glue looks like this:

```
using System;
using Autofac;

namespace DemoApp
{
   public class Program
   {
     private static IContainer Container { get; set; }

   static void Main(string[] args)
   {
       var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
       builder.RegisterType<ConsoleOutput>().As<IOutput>();
       builder.RegisterType<TodayWriter>().As<IDateWriter>();
       Container = builder.Build();

       WriteDate();
   }
  }
}


public static void WriteDate()
 {
  // Create the scope, resolve your IDateWriter,
  // use it, then dispose of the scope.
  using (var scope = Container.BeginLifetimeScope())
  {
    var writer = scope.Resolve<IDateWriter>();
    writer.WriteDate();
  }
}
```

The purpose of this program is simply to print the datetime on the console. Suppose now that I want to print the datetime not only in the console but also in the logs. For this purpose i want to create another class having interface IOutput like this:

```
public class LogsOutput : IOutput
{
    public void Write(string content)
    {
        // write content to a log file here
    }
 }
```

This is a pure example. I want to extend this example to a bigger problem.
Now how should look like the Autofac glue code ? in order for the code to execute both ConsoleOutput classe and LogsOutput class and to print the output to both the console and the log file ?

Is it possible to achieve this with Autofac or is this not in the behaviour of autofac ?
I possibly want to ba able to add hundreds of classes all with the IOutput interface. How to achieve this with Autofac ?

Comment: You should look at [decorator](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/adapters-decorators.html) or [interceptor](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/interceptors.html). Let me know if you like example based on your case

Comment: Why the downvote ? Maybe the question should be redacted ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After creating a new `IOutput` type,

First you need to register it in the container, using [Named](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/keyed-services.html#named-services):

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterType<ConsoleOutput>().Named<IOutput>("console");
builder.RegisterType<LogsOutput>().Named<IOutput>("logs");
builder.RegisterType<TodayWriter>().As<IDateWriter>();
Container = builder.Build();
```

Then, in the `WriteDate()` method you specify type of `Ioutput` to use by calling `ResolveNamed` method with `name` parameter, which is the name specified in the registration of the type :

```
public static void WriteDate()
 {
  // Create the scope, resolve your IDateWriter,
  // use it, then dispose of the scope.
  using (var scope = Container.BeginLifetimeScope())
  {
    var writer = scope.ResolveNamed<IDateWriter>("console"); // for console output
    //var writer = scope.ResolveNamed<IDateWriter>("logs"); // for logs output
    writer.WriteDate();
  }
}
```

NB : if you don't work with `string` names, you can use [Keyed](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/keyed-services.html#keyed-services) which work with `enumeration`s .

Comment: Thanks much appreciated. i see twice. var writer . a typo maybe ?

Comment: Yes, i updated the answer, i wanted to show you how to instanciate the `writer` in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

AutoFac directly supports this by taking a dependency on `IEnumerable<T>`.  When it sees the `IEnumerable`, it will return a collection of all registered types that satisfy the interface `T`.

In your case register *both* `LogsOutput`, and `ConsoleOutput` as `IOutput`, and resolve  `IEnumerable<IOutput>`, to get both registered services.

---

More details can be found [here](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/resolve/relationships.html#enumeration-ienumerable-b-ilist-b-icollection-b).

> Dependencies of an enumerable type provide multiple implementations of
>   the same service (interface). This is helpful in cases like message
>   handlers, where a message comes in and more than one handler is
>   registered to process the message.